# Fail to insert date range to more than one select option tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
    <?php
       require_once('dbconfig.php');
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM kpi_detail";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       ?>
       <tbody>
           <tr id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
           <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['kpi_name'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['target'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['current_data'] ?></td>
           <td><input type="text" id="dt1" value="<?php echo $row['start_date'] ?>"></td>
           <td><input type="text" id="dt2" value="<?php echo $row['end_date'] ?>"></td>
           <td><button type="submit" onclick="SubmitDate();">Save</button></td>
           <td><select name="DateList"><option selected>Select date</option></select></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
       <?php } ?></table>
       <script type="text/javascript">

        var startDate = new Date($('#dt1').val()); //YYYY-MM-DD
        var endDate = new Date($('#dt2').val()); //YYYY-MM-DD
        console.log($('#dt1').val());
        var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
        var arr = new Array();
        var dt = new Date(start);
        while (dt <= end) {
            arr.push(new Date(dt));
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return arr;
    }

        var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);

        var sel =  document.querySelector("select[name='DateList']");
        for (var i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = dateArr[i].toLocaleDateString("en-US");
        opt.value = dateArr[i].toLocaleDateString("en-US");
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    }

    </script>
```

After I insert the first data and select the start Date and end Date in a form, the value of start Date and end Date will store in the date Arr JavaScript variable. If I insert another data in the form and select the start Date and end Date, the second data onward won't receive the date of start Date to end Date. Need a solution to get every value of date I had selected and insert in the select option value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sKVb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X181X.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code in these statements

```
       <td><input type="text" id="dt1" value="<?php echo $row['start_date'] ?>"></td>
       <td><input type="text" id="dt2" value="<?php echo $row['end_date'] ?>"></td>
```

Use class instead of ids as there will many duplicate ids. So change your code like this:

```
       <td><input type="text" class="dt1" value="<?php echo $row['start_date'] ?>" id="<?php echo $row['start_date'] ?>"></td>
       <td><input type="text" class="dt2" value="<?php echo $row['end_date'] ?>" id="<?php echo $row['end_date'] ?>"></td>
```

Now in your JQuery code you can get values like this:

```
$(".dt1").on('change',function()
{
  var start_date=$(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" class="startDate" value="<?php echo $row['start_date'] ?>">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="endDate" value="<?php echo $row['end_date'] ?>">
</td>
```

And in your JS:

```
   var getDateArray = function (start, end) {
        var arr = new Array();
        var dt = new Date(start);
        end = new Date(end);
        while (dt <= end) {
            arr.push(new Date(dt));
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return arr;
    };

    $("tr").each(
        function (index) {
            var startDate = $(this).find('.startDate').attr('value');
            var endDate = $(this).find('.endDate').attr('value');
            var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);
            var sel = $(this).find("select[name='DateList']");
            for (var i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
                var value = dateArr[i].toLocaleDateString("en-US");
                var opt = new Option(value, value);
                sel.append(opt);
            }
        }
    );
```

There are a couple of problems in your code that should be fixed: you should not use same ID for diffreent elements. The tbody element also should be outside of your loop.